# \mathbb{Z} yields undefined control sequence error

Tags: math-mode, errors, symbols

I am using WinEdt 6 for compiling my TeX documents. I am getting an error with contains the line `$\mathbb{Z}$` showing that it is undefined control sequence. How should I rectify it? Should I include any math packages or something. I am a beginner in using TeX.

Comment: This was my very first LaTeX error!  It took me days to figure out; no online resource I read thought to mention that it was assuming the `amssymb` package.

Comment: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=numbersets describes the AMS fonts, and says "Support files for using the fonts, both under Plain TeX and LaTeX (packages amssymb and amsfonts), are available. [...]".  this of course doesn't help, if you're a person who doesn't like to read faq answers...

Comment: did you try `\usepackage{amsfonts}`? I don't think anything else is needed in a very basic overleaf new doc.

Answer (score 305, accepted):

Load the `amsfonts` package, this provides that command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
$\mathbb{Z}$
\end{document}
```

Optionally you could load `amssymb`, as this in turn loads `amsfonts`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
$\mathbb{Z}$
\end{document}
```

For reference, the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive) has also a table of mathematical alphabets, and the packages required for using them. In the current version (dated 25 June 2020) of the document, it is table 316 with the caption *Math Alphabets*. It is the final table in chapter 3 *Mathematical symbols*.

Comment: Thank you. Would the same be sufficient for \mathds??

Comment: @RamanaVenkata No, for that you have to load the `dsfont` package.

Comment: I guess the document you reference is subject to chance, if other people are looking for it here a description that is hopefully less prone to change. Look at the chapter called Mathematical symbols (currently chapter 3) and look for the table called "mathematical alphabets". It is last table in that chapter at this moment and currently numbered 307.

Comment: @koffie Indeed. I updated the text in my answer a bit.

Comment: Apparently `amsmath` does not load `amsfonts` automatically.

Comment: @SolomonUcko -- Indeed, `amsmath` does not load `amsfonts`.  When these packages were created, memory was at a premium, and loading of necessary packages was left to the user.

Comment: which of the two is better? Giving two options is confusing without further remarks.

Comment: all you need is `\usepackage{amsfonts}` the rest of the answer is confusing.

Comment: @CharlieParker Yes, perhaps mentioning `amssymb` was unnecessary, I can't remember now why I added it in the first place ... It wasn't completely without further remarks though, I do say that `amssymb` is an option because "this in turn loads `amsfonts`". So in that sense they do exactly the same thing with regard to `\mathbb`.  What `amssymb` does more is to provide definitions for various mathematical symbols.

Answer (score 6):

The `\mathbb` command is provided via the `amsfonts` package. Add

```
\usepackage{amsfonts}
```

to the preamble to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can load many other fonts for `\mathbb` with either `unicode-math`, which supports modern OpenType math fonts, or `mathalpha`, which supports legacy 8-bit math alphabets.

Comment: using `\usepackage{amsfonts}` is easier, no?

Comment: @CharlieParker obviously that depends on your document. If you want some other alphabets, like script and other not provided by `amsfonts` you will end up loading many more packages than just `unicode-math`. Another example when `unicode-math` is more useful is when you need to load many fonts (not recommended but it is possible). You have to give a try to `unicode-math` and decide by yourself which package is better in certain contexts.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following two packages.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Your answer adds nothing new to the already existing answers.

Comment: While true that blackboard bold Z will appear if these two packages are used, only `amsfonts` is needed, and that is loaded automatically by `amssymb`.