# How to use small caps black board bold font?

Tags: fonts

Based on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38769/mathbbz-yields-undefined-control-sequence-error) I really expected the following to work:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
    $\mathbb{c,g,d,h,t}$
\end{document}
```

However, out comes something looking like this:

[image]

I have also tried the `amsfonts` package with the same results. Clearly I have missed something, but what?

Comment: Your expectations were too optimistic: somebody has to draw those symbols and have a good reason to. I'm not really sure anybody has had one until now.

Comment: I found a lot of them here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackboard_bold and thought they were commonly used...

Comment: One of the bad influences Mathematica™ has had on typesetting.

Comment: the lowercase blackboard bold alphabet has been included in unicode, so these letters are in the `stix` and `xits` fonts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In such case where small letter will fail, you need `\usepackage{bbm}` and use `\mathbbm{...}`

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bbm}
\begin{document}
$\mathbbm{c,g,d,h,t}$

$\mathbb{R,C}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't `bbm` still in Type3 format? ie. may look ragged when scalled up (some publishers will not accept Typo3 fonts).

Comment: @daleif -- Yes, I believe so. I picked up and came to know this knowledge while having this same trouble typing math.

Comment: Very much confirmed. It looks terrible :(

Comment: @jonalv -- Thank you for the information. I know there is(was?) a package called `doublestroke` which is of type 1, but it is unavailable currently at CTAN. The command to use for this package is `\mathds{...}`.

Comment: The package [`doublestroke`](https://ctan.org/pkg/doublestroke) is on CTAN, but it does not contain lower case double stroke letters except for  and .