# Paper Submission Accordingly

Tags: paper, research

I downloaded the Latex template file from a mathematics journal site so that I can write my article according to the journal submission guidelines. Now as I am trying to write it's not running. I tried to add corresponding packages but then again there is a problem. Even `$\mathbb $` is not working. Please suggest what I could do. I am adding picture of that [image]

In textfile it is

```
\documentclass{bmcart}

\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath}

\def\includegraphic{}

\def\includegraphics{}

\startlocaldefs

\endlocaldefs

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\begin{fmbox}

\dochead{Research}

\title{The  }


\author[
  addressref={aff1},                   % id's of addresses, e.g. {aff1,aff2}
  corref={aff1},                       % id of corresponding address, if any
% noteref={n1},                        % id's of article notes, if any
  email={jane.e.doe@cambridge.co.uk}   % email address
]{\inits{J.E.}\fnm{Jane E.} \snm{Doe}}
\author[
  addressref={aff1,aff2},
  email={john.RS.Smith@cambridge.co.uk}
]{\inits{J.R.S.}\fnm{John R.S.} \snm{Smith}}


\address[id=aff1]{%                           % unique id
  \orgdiv{Department of Science},             % department, if any
  \orgname{University of Cambridge},          % university, etc
  \city{London},                              % city
  \cny{UK}                                    % country
}
\address[id=aff2]{%
  \orgdiv{Institute of Biology},
  \orgname{National University of Sciences},
  %\street{},
  %\postcode{}
  \city{Kiel},
  \cny{Germany}
}



\end{fmbox}% comment this for two column layout

\begin{abstractbox}

\begin{abstract} % abstract
\parttitle{First part title} %if any
Text for this section.

\parttitle{Second part title} %if any
Text for this section.
\end{abstract}
```

Comment: Please provide example code, as short as possible but still complete with the documentclass, usepackage statements, and a small bit of contents with `\mathbb`, as an edit to your question. Also provide a link where we can find the template online. Finally, provide the exact text of the error message(s) that you get. With that information we will probably be able to help you, without it we can't do much.

Comment: @Japer Habitat Thank you sir. Actually I am NOT fluent in Latex .

Comment: Thanks for the code. However, it is not yet complete: it is missing some `\end` statements, for the `abstractbox`, the `fontmatter`, and the `document`. Also it doesn't demonstrate the use of `\mathbb`. Furthermore you did not provide a link for the documentclass or the text of the error message that you get. Can you add those missing pieces of information as well?

Comment: @Marijn I just type the portion of packages .

Comment: @Marijn unable to add details. I am trying to add more details.

Comment: Does [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38769/106162) answer your question?

Comment: @DaiBowen no still problem

Comment: Adding `\usepackage{amsfonts}` will add `\mathbb`; that is the answer given in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38769 as already suggested.  I don't know the document class `bcmart` and how it defines `\title`; it may be necessary to input this as `\protect\mathbb`.

Answer (score 1):

You need, of course,

```
\usepackage{amsfonts}
```

or

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
```

However, the class does strange things, but if you have

```
\startlocaldefs
\newcommand{\RR}{}
\protected\def\RR{\mathbb{R}}
\endlocaldefs
```

then

```
\title{The $\RR$}
```

will work. Why the `\newcommand`? Because it will tell you whether `\RR` is already defined, in which case you can use a different name.